# Checking user info with multiple parameters

Tags: linux, bash

I have to print information about the user with the name given as a parameter. For example let's say

./script1.sh John
should give me

John Doe (username) -last login-

I think I managed this, but I also have to check multiple parameters like

./script1.sh John Jane Etrjk

John Doe (username) -last login-

Jane Doe (username) -last login

Etrjk not found

and I do not know how to use multiple parameters in my script
this is my script so far (works for 1 parameter):

```
if [ -z "$1 ]
then
echo "no arguments"
exit
fi

var = $1

if grep -q "$1" /etc/passwd
then
echo "FOUND"
awk 'BEGIN {FS = ":" }; /'$1'/ {print $5,$1}' /etc/passwd
var2=$(awk 'BEGIN {FS = ":" }; /'$1'/ {print $1}' /etc/passwd
lastlog -u $var2 | awk 'NR==2 {print $4,$5,$6}'
else
echo "not found"

fi
```

Comment: `var = $1` -- no spaces allowed around the equal sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll do:

```sh
for name in "$@"; do 
...
done
```

The shell allows the shorhand `for name do` to iterate over the positional parameters. I prefer to be explicit about it.

The safe way to pass parameters into awk is with the `-v` option:

```sh
username=$(awk -v name="$name" 'BEGIN {FS = ":" }; $0 ~ name {print $1}' /etc/passwd)
```

I suggest you get into the habit of using meaningful variable names. It will help anyone (including you) who is reading your code.

Comment: Of just `for name` ;)